# undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)' in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

i am using opencv with cuda 6.5 , when i try to compile this code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace cv;

int main() {
Mat src = imread("mini.jpg", 0);

if (!src.data) exit(1);
gpu::GpuMat d_src(src);
gpu::GpuMat d_dst;
gpu::bilateralFilter(d_src, d_dst, -1, 50, 7);
gpu::Canny(d_dst, d_dst, 35, 200, 3);
Mat dst(d_dst);
imwrite("out.png", dst);
return 0;
}
```

i got those errors:

```
ubuntu32@Dell32:~/Templates/openCV$ nvcc gpu.cu `pkg-config --cflags
--libs opencv` /tmp/tmpxft_000016c6_00000000-16_gpu.o: In function `main': tmpxft_000016c6_00000000-3_gpu.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)' tmpxft_000016c6_00000000-3_gpu.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

For openCV 3.X you need to add library imgcodecs to project.

Comment: how i can add it ??! i tried different ways but it required to install hole the package thanks...

Comment: You need OpenCV installed on your system to use it. http://answers.opencv.org/question/25642/how-to-compile-basic-opencv-program-in-c-in-ubuntu/ , additionally you need to append "-lopencv_imgcodecs" .

Comment: How about OpenCV 2.X ?